# Dell optiplex 7010 won’t boot up with a green flashing piwer button

Tags: computer-building

I put an gtx 1660ti into my dell optiplex 7010, and put in an add. Now the computer power button is blinking green. Does anybody know what the problem is?

Comment: I mean an ssd. Please somebody help me!

Comment: See https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-gb/sln284978/a-reference-guide-to-the-dell-optiplex-diagnostic-indicators?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Dell Support article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln284978/a-reference-guide-to-the-dell-optiplex-diagnostic-indicators?lang=en), on Diagnostic LEDs for the OptiPlex series (2005 to 2009) section, a blinking green power led means:

> The system is in a hibernate or sleep state.

As you have inserted a new hdd, maybe before doing it you put your PC in hibernation or sleep. You will need to wake the PC up.